# Swashbuckle returns nullreferenceexception

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger

I have started to use swashbuckle for my rest api.

When I go to localhost:port/swagger

I get the following runtime error:

> System.Nullreferenceexception in
>   Swashbuckle.Application.SwaggerDocsConfig.Getswaggerprovider(Httprequestmessage
>   swaggerRequest)

I initialized swashbuckle like this:

```
var config = new Httpconfiguration();
config.EnableSwagger();
```

Please, help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

guys

The issue was resolved. I simply recreated my asp.net project, added model, referenced swagger and it is all OK.